# pstricks with old latex-dvips-ps2pdf worked; fails with 2014 TeXLive xelatex

Tags: xetex, pstricks

I have drawings using pstricks that worked just fine in an old (2008) version of LaTex.  On a new machine I switched to texlive 2014 and using xelatex the drawings do not work.  For example, the following worked with the latex-dvips-ps2pdf chain of commands, but does not work in xelatex (it produces ghostscript errors) and the figure is incomplete:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2in,-2in)(2in,2in)
\rput{45}(0,0){%
   \pscircle(0,0){2}
   \pstextpath[t]{\psarc[linecolor=white](0,0){2.1}{-90}{0}}{deferent}
   \psline[arrows=<-,linewidth=1.5pt](-0.01,2)(0.01,2)
   }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

```
(emr.reingold.co-1) xelatex \\nonstopmode\\input junk.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.

(./junk.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pst-all.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
))
`PSTricks' v2.60  <2014/10/25> (tvz)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg
Using PSTricks configuration for XeTeX+xdvipdfmx
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-plot/pst-plot.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/pst-xkey.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multido/multido.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/multido/multido.tex
 v1.42, 2010/05/14 <tvz>))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-plot/pst-plot.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-tools/pst-tools.tex
`PST-tools' v0.05, 2014/05/12 (hv))  v1.70, 2014/08/23 (tvz,hv)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-node/pst-node.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-node/pst-node.tex
 v1.35, 2014/08/04))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-tree/pst-tree.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-tree/pst-tree.tex
 v1.12, 2011/02/28(tvz,dg,hv)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-grad/pst-grad.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-grad/pst-grad.tex
`pst-grad' v1.06, 2006/11/27 (tvz,dg,hv)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-coil/pst-coil.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-coil/pst-coil.tex
 v1.06, 2006/11/27
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-node/pst-node.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-text/pst-text.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-text/pst-text.tex
 v1.00, 2006/11/05(tvz,hv)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-3d/pst-3d.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-3d/pst-3d.tex
`PST-3d' v1.11, 2010/02/14 (tvz)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-eps/pst-eps.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-eps/pst-eps.tex
 v1.00, 2006/11/04))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-fill/pst-fill.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-fill/pst-fill.tex
`PST-Fill' v1.01, 2007/03/10 (tvz,dg,hv)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks-add/pstricks-add.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-math/pst-math.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-math/pst-math.tex
`pst-math' v0.63 , (CJ,hv)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks-add/pstricks-add.tex
`pstricks-add' v3.77, 2014/12/08 (dr,hv))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks-add/pstricks-add.cfg)))
(./junk.aux) [1] (./junk.aux)Error: /undefined in --load--
Operand stack:
   show   tx@TextPathSavedShow
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1910   1   3   %oparray_pop   1909   1   3   %oparray_pop   1893   1   3   %oparray_pop   1787   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1910   1   3   %oparray_pop   1909   1   3   %oparray_pop   1893   1   3   %oparray_pop   1787   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1173/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:166/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 1490
GPL Ghostscript 9.06: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
 )
Output written on junk.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on junk.log.
(emr.reingold.co-2)
```

Comment: it gives same error in 2015, odd thing it is a postscript error but xetex specific, if you use latex/dvips/ps2pdf then it runs without error and produces [this output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/h6Tvi.png)

Comment: it is a problem with PostScripts  show operator and not solved yet.